# Ember testing components that have helpers that use services

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli

Say I have this inside a component:

```
{{#if (has-spotify)}}
  <i class="fa fa-spotify" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i>
{{else}}
  <i class="fa fa-spotify" {{action "authSpotify"}}></i>
{{/if}}
```

And the `has-spotify` helper has this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function hasSpotify() {
  return this.get('spotifyService.spotifyInfo').then((result) =>{
    return result !== undefined;
  });
}

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  spotifyService: Ember.inject.service(),
  compute: hasSpotify
});
```

And the spotifyService makes a call to our API.

How can I stub that helper inside the components test?

Comment: Just a note: your helper probably doesn't work. You can't return a promise from a helper and have the template re-render when it settles. [Take a look at ember-promise-helpers](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers) for a really useful `await` helper to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stub the service using `getOwner` and `register` in your integration test:

```
test('when spotify service fails', function(assert) {
  let stub = Ember.Service.extend({ spotifyInfo: undefined });

  Ember.getOwner(this).register('service:spotify-service', stub);

  this.render(hbs`{{spotify-song}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), 'Log in', 'asks for log in');
});
```

[Here's an Ember Twiddle with a simplified version of your component, helper, and service, and working integration tests](https://ember-twiddle.com/00756de8c248bb5ced47cd2ea9e23b5a?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=tests.integration.components.spotify-song-test.js%2Ctemplates.components.spotify-song.hbs).

#### More Details

Your helper returns a promise, which is always truthy and means that your sample component will never hit the second branch. [Look at ember-promise-helpers](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers) for a way around this.

To answer your testing question, I've simplified your helper not to use promises, as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function hasSpotify() {
  return this.get('spotifyService.spotifyInfo') !== undefined;
}

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  spotifyService: Ember.inject.service(),
  compute: hasSpotify
});
```

Here's the "normal" Spotify service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  spotifyInfo: { username: 'alisdair' }
});
```

And here's the simpler component template:

```
{{#if (has-spotify)}}
  Song info
{{else}}
  Log in
{{/if}}
```

The happy path integration test looks like this:

```
test('normal usage', function(assert) {
  this.render(hbs`{{spotify-song}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), 'Song info', 'shows song info');
});
```

This is using the real service and helper, so everything works as normal.

To inject a stub service onto your helper, you need to create a replacement service object. Then use `Ember.getOwner` to register the stub under the same name as your original service, and render out your component:

```
let spotifyService = Ember.Service.extend({ spotifyInfo: undefined });

Ember.owner.register('service:spotify-service', spotifyService);

this.render(hbs`{{spotify-song}}`);
```

Your helper will then inject this stub service, which you can use to change its behaviour to test however you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! And the promise helpers look like exactly what i need in a few other places - why aren't these a part of the main ember cli offering?!